# How to reuse Maven profile?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-profiles

We have multiple independent maven projects that use two profiles. Currently, these profiles are part of `pom.xml` and copied to all projects. Is there a way to reuse the Maven profile across all services?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [maven-tiles](https://github.com/repaint-io/maven-tiles). But I don't know if that supports profiles as well.

Comment: I would always ask: Why do you need profiles and two? Make it part of your parents... ?

Comment: not via some import mechanism. you can add profiles into settings.xml and distribute that. or as mentioned via a common parent pom file. even if the profile is not inherited, its effects are.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Maven-tiles looks interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place profiles in a parent POM and use that parent in your projects.

Then the projects inherit the profiles from the parent POM.

Note that you do not need to create a multi-module project for that. An ordinary parent POM suffices.